# facebook instant articles not working

Tags: drupal-7, facebook-instant-articles

Please tell me if i have done something wrong in doing the FBIA

1. Created an XML Feed
2. Went to facebook to config, claimed url (claimed successfully)
3. Input RSS feed in the development rss feed input
4. Went to the development articles tab did not see anything
5. Went back to config to force fetch of the articles
6. Went to the development articles tab and still did not see anything

Guys any reason or ideas why its not fetching the articles?

Thank you!